# How to stop React from using favicon from _Layout.cshtml instead of webpack.config.js?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, webpack

I have a React app with TypeScript, but it seems to be using _Layout.cshtml to display the favicon instead of webpack.config.js generating index.html.

_Layout.cshtml has this line:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="~/dist/favicon.ico" />
```

webpack.config.js:

```
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
   favicon: './ClientApp/content/favicon.ico'
}),
```

index.html:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/dist/favicon.ico">
```

I haven't been able to find anything about how React decides to use webpack instead of the layout. Removing favicon from _Layout.cshtml just leaves it as a default icon instead of falling back on the one I've defined in webpack.

Is there something else I need to disable or change in order to force it to use the webpack version? The reason I want to do this is because I need to show two different favicons based on something that is set inside the React app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't figure out how *not* to use _Layout.cshtml, so I just worked with it inside the React JavaScript code.

First I removed the lines from `webpack.config.js` and `index.html`. I think the latter is generated from the former, so removing it from there isn't necessary probably. But as I said, none of that code seemed to be affecting anything anyway.

Then I changed the line in _Layout.cshtml to the following:

```
<link id="favicon" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="" />
```

That prevented it from displaying any favicon initially, important because of the reason for needing two icons. It also gave me an ID I could grab in the JavaScript.

Finally, I added this JS code:

```
const favicon = document.getElementById("favicon");
if (useNormalFavicon) {
    favicon.setAttribute("href", "/dist/favicon_normal.ico")
} else {
    favicon.setAttribute("href", "/dist/favicon_special.ico")
}
```

You'd have to decide exactly where to put that code depending on the design of your solution. I put it into one of the lowest level .tsx files that is used as the base for most of the site's UI.

Answer (score 0):

I have never seen `_Layout.cshtml` or `webpack.config.js` when I `npx create-react-app`. I believe it is not recommended to edit files with the prefix `_`.

If you want to use the favicon on `./ClientApp/content/favicon.ico`, I think you would better replace `public/favicon.ico` with it.